# spring jdbc connection with hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:

Comment: <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/"/>
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean >
 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="hr" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="hr" />
 </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]  . check whether oracle jar is added and present in classpath

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Missing artifact ojdbc:ojdbc:jar:14. I am getting this error.... jar is there in my class path.                                                                                                            .<dependency>
      <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
      <version>14</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar</systemPath> <!-- must match file name -->
  </dependency>

Comment: make it default scope and try or else add external jar to the build path.system : 
This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.